# Training MXNet Faster R-CNN on own data set

Tags: python, mxnet

I was using the mxnet example for Faster R-CNN on the official GitHub:
[Faster R-CNN](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/tree/master/example/rcnn)

I created my own dataset and adapted the `pascal_voc.py` file. This included changing the number of classes to 13.
The resolution of my pictures is 600*800 pixel, so a bit larger than the VOC dataset.
In my trainval images, I have 2000 examples, so 3000 less than than in VOC.
I am using mxnet 0.10 in python for this.

I am getting no error in the training, the loss is decreasing, but when I use the model after 10 epochs, I am getting no results, just the:

```
class ---- [[x1, x2, y1, y2, confidence]]
```

Does anyone has an idea what I am might missing?

Comment: What do you mean "use the model...", what code are you running? You will get this output if the model didn't find any box in the input.

Comment: Hi Guy, I am running the example from github that I mentioned in the link. But instead of the 21 original classes, I defined 13 classes (Faces). Yes that I know, and I am now very sure that I am lacking training data (My dataset is too small)

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with gluon, a flexible interface of mxnet, do you mind to try the Faster RCNN example from GluonCV:

https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/build/examples_detection/train_faster_rcnn_voc.html